# Control autorotation from a view controller without modifying the rest of the app

Tags: ios, ios7, uiviewcontroller

I'm developing an iOS framework. It contains a view controller that can be displayed modally by the app that will be using my framework. I don't have access to the app code, just my framework. I'd like to prevent autorotation when my view controller is being displayed. Can this be done? I've tried returning `NO` from `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` in my VC, but that doesn't get called.

Comment: If you are using iOS 6.0 or later, then it should be the shouldAutorotate function, since shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: has been deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You could add this code to your AppDelegate. It will allow other viewControllers to respond to autorotation calls.

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
/* This is in order to allow views that do not support landscape mode to be able to load in
 */
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Also, in iOS 6.0 and later the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method has been deprecated. It could be substituted by the following methods:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: The problem is I don't have access to the code of the app, including the app delegate. I provide a view controller in my library that is used by an app. I need to prevent rotation while my view controller is displayed.

Comment: I'm assuming you know who has access to the appDelegate, and ask him/her to add that code to it. And then your normal autorotation functions, as mentioned above, should work. It will not work unless that particular method is the appDelegate. I just checked it now.